# is there any max number for sections while adding to card in googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any max number for sections while adding to card in googlescript?

I have a card with **13** sections in it, but it displays only **12** sections, Is there any specific limit on adding sections to the card

I have multiple sections which are going to add dynamically to the card,Is this possible to add **n** number of sections to the card?.

Comment: Can you show some code? Where are these cards supposed to show up? Hangouts? Gmail? Another Application?

Comment: i'm developing Gmail addon with appscript where i have faced above issue.

Sample Code :
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
 card.addSection();
 card.addSection();
 card.addSection() .....  we are adding multiple sections dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to share your code?
I tried creating such a structure and was able to add 15 elements with no problems. You can see my code [here](https://pastebin.com/dLqpPaxG)

Comment: Sorry i can't share my code, It is a complex structure with multiple widgets within single section, and multiple sections with in single card, Widgets and sections where from the API.

Please help me out, do we have any restrictions in adding n number of widgets to sections or n number of sections to Card, Is there any specific count for widgets or sections in Gmail addon building.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as of now the limit of sections a Card can have is 100.

However, 13 items are not a problem. The problem you are facing lies somewhere else in your code. Without that information we are not able to help.

As proof, here is some code that successfully shows how to adds 15 widgets:

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  var tempsections = [];
  for (var i =0 ; i<15; i++) {
    var tempsection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Texts '+ i + 'aaaa.');
    tempsection.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText("Sections num"+i).setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("test")));
    tempsections.push(tempsection);
  }

  // Build the main card after adding the section.
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('Quick Label')
    .setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_googblue_48dp.png'))
    .addSection(tempsections[0])
    .addSection(tempsections[1])
    .addSection(tempsections[2])
    .addSection(tempsections[3])
    .addSection(tempsections[4])
    .addSection(tempsections[5])
    .addSection(tempsections[6])
    .addSection(tempsections[7])
    .addSection(tempsections[8])
    .addSection(tempsections[9])
    .addSection(tempsections[10])
    .addSection(tempsections[11])
    .addSection(tempsections[12])
    .addSection(tempsections[13])
    .addSection(tempsections[14])
    .build();

  return [card];
} 

function test() {
  return 0;
}
```

Also, for proof, here is the change to add 101 sections:

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  var tempsections = [];
  for (var i =0 ; i<101; i++) {
    var tempsection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Texts '+ i + 'aaaa.');
    tempsection.addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText("Sections num"+i).setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("test")));
    tempsections.push(tempsection);
  }

  // Build the main card after adding the section.
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('Quick Label')
    .setImageUrl('https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_googblue_48dp.png'));
  for (var i =0 ; i<101; i++) {
    card = card.addSections(tempsections[i]);
  }
  card = card.build();

  return [card];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, 
Yes your right if i use 15 sections its working, but i have used same logic for 120 sections, it got failed, full 120 sections were not loading, few of the sections were not displaying, can you please try with 120+ sections, is it working?
Thanks for helping to resolve, i'm running with my time with this one issue.

Comment: @SatishGoudBanda I have updated my answer. You are indeed correct. The limit seems to be 100 sections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sections we have 100 in the same way do we have any limit on widgets count also, if i have reduced the few widgets in my  logic i'm able to see remaining sections as well, Please help me out is any specific restrictions on widgets count also, 

Thanks

Comment: @SatishGoudBanda I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain here is sample code for section 
var section = CardService.newCardSection();
section.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setMultiline(true).setContent("text"));section.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setMultiline(true).setContent("text"));........ like this we may have multiple widgets for one section, in my case i have multiple sections with this multiple widgets in loop, We can have only 100 sections in a card, in the same way do we have any specific limit for total number of widgets in the card.
Thanks

Comment: @SatishGoudBanda this seems like a new question. Please post a new question with relevant information, minimal reproducible code and enough information for others to help you. Also, remember to accept answers that are helpful to you as StackOverflow relies on this to deliver knowledge to other users.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i think we have limit on widgets also, I will post as a new question.
Thanks.